Trouble with search form exposure in WordPress
I'm having trouble displaying the results of a CiviCRM search as a page in WordPress, I'm hoping someone can see what I'm doing wrong.
I have a saved SearchKit form called "Current Singers" (it's a search for everyone in the CiviCRM group "Current Singers", appropriately enough).  It has 1 display, called "Roster Table", which displays 5 simple fields (name, section, city, phone, email) as a table.
What I would like to do is display this table on a page for any logged-in WordPress user, regardless of whether that user has specific CiviCRM permissions or not (almost none do, except for me & a couple other people).  If the user is not logged in, they should see no data.
I can't seem to get this to work, though.  For one thing, I can't seem to find a permission for "any authenticated user".  For another thing, even if I use the permission "Generic: Allow all users (including anonymous)", a logged-in user still sees a blank table:

When I log in as a CiviCRM administrator, I can see the correct content, so I know the underlying search is working correctly.
This is where I'm setting permissions, is there some other permission setting I'm overlooking?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I'm using CiviCRM version 5.66.2 (and in the process of upgrading to a newer version, hoping that fixes something) and WordPress version 6.6.1.

In the Roster Table, under 'Options' what do you have set in the 'Security' dropdown?

Aha - I didn't find an "Options" or "Security" section (possibly because my version is old), but I did find a "Bypass Permissions" button that did the trick.  My confusion was that I couldn't tell whether the button reflected the current state, or pressing the button would enact that state.

@AndyClark I'm happy to write that up as a solution with a screenshot for the next person, or if you write it up I'll accept it.

I'd upgrade to a current version of Civi first and see how that works out.
